# How does autocommit work with multiple queries?

Tags: python, psycopg2

I have a psycopg connection with autocommit turned on. Say, I run a query that is a combination of multiple queries, e.g.:

```
query = ";".join([create_table, insert_data, analyze_table])
conn.execute(query)
```

Is this batch executed in a single transaction or multiple transactions? What happens if a query in the middle fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Chain multiple statements within Psycopg2](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/chain-multiple-statements-within-psycopg2/)

> In SQL chaining refers to the process of linking multiple SQL
> statements together into a single string, separated by semicolons.
> This allows you to execute multiple SQL statements at once, without
> having to execute them individually.
>
> For example, you might chain together a SELECT statement to retrieve
> data from a table, followed by an UPDATE statement to modify the data,
> and then a DELETE statement to remove it. **When using chaining, it is
> important to note that each statement will be executed in the order
> they appear in the chain and that the results of one statement can be
> used in the next one. Additionally, when chaining SQL statements, if
> any statement in the chain fails, the entire chain will fail and none
> of the statements will be executed.**

Comment: ... or in simpler words (and database parlance): if you send multiple statements in a single command, they will be executed in a single transaction.

Comment: Not official docs, but this seems to agree with my own tests.

Comment: @planetp, actually it is in the docs [Message flow](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/protocol-flow.html) section *55.2.2.1. Multiple Statements in a Simple Query*.